# VB.net populating database query result to listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

How to populate database query results to a listview. I am having problem with the line "Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = myRow.Item(0)".

```
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim WFTeam As New DataSet()
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim myRow As DataRow
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strSqlStm As String = ""
    Dim strConnectionString As String = ""


        strSqlStm = "SELECT [SRF#], [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [Agent] WHERE [TeamLeaderNo] = 103"
        cn.ConnectionString = strDataSource & "Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase;" & strUID & strPassword
        cn.Open()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(strSqlStm, cn)
        cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(WFTeam, "Team")
        WFTeam.Tables.Add(dt)
        da.Fill(dt)

        Form1.ListView1.Items.Clear()

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        For Each myRow In dt.Rows
            If Not IsDBNull(myRow.Item(0)) Then

                Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = myRow.Item(0)
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(myRow.Item(1)) Then
                Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text = myRow.Item(1)
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(myRow.Item(2)) Then
                Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = myRow.Item(2)
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next

        cn.Close()
```

Following code works but I need to access a particular item just like Excel

```
    For Each myRow In dt.Rows

    If Not IsDBNull(myRow.Item(0)) Then
       Form1.ListView1.Items.Add(myRow.Item(0))
       'Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = myRow.Item(0)
    End If
    If Not IsDBNull(myRow.Item(1)) Then
       Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(1))
      'Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text = myRow.Item(1)
    End If
    If Not IsDBNull(myRow.Item(2)) Then
       Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
      'Form1.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = myRow.Item(2)
   End If
   i = i + 1
   Next
```

Comment: Right away I can see you're trying to add to an item that doesn't exist. You've cleared `ListView1.Items` and then immediately try to set the value of `Items(1).SubItems(1)`. You need to do a `ListView1.Items.Add()` first.

Comment: "having problem" is not very descriptive.  I can see you clear the Items; that means you need to create new items with the new data for the LV.  There are no Items or SubItems after you clear it

Comment: the new code will not work when the first item is DbNull - you cannot add SubItems when there is no Item.  it will also put `myRow.Item(2)` in column 1 when `myRow.Item(1)` is DbNull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cleared the LV, so there are no Items or SubItems to populate.  You need to create new ListViewItems and populate them with the DB data.  But your edit skips adding an Item if the first filed IsDbNull which means you cannot add anything for that record.  The following will also "anchor" the data so when any subitem data IsDbNull, the next subitems dont shift over one:

```
Form1.ListView1.Items.Clear()

Dim lvi As ListViewItem
For Each myRow In dt.Rows

    ' create NEW listview item for this row
    lvi = New ListViewItem
    If IsDBNull(myRow.Item(0)) Then
        lvi.Text = " "           ' blank Item 
    Else         
        lvi.Text = myRow.Item(0)
    End If

    ' repeat for the sub items, adding blanks when DbNull

    If IsDBNull(myRow.Item(1)) Then
        lvi.SubItems.Add(" ")
    Else
        lvi.SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(1))
    End If

    ' etc

    Form1.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

Next
```

A `DataGridView` would be much more suited to this than a `ListView`, especially to access items similar to Excel.  I take this to mean you want `myRow.Item(2)` to always be the second subitem.  So, the code above adds empty Items or SubItems as "placeholders".